# Checkboxes in Rails Forms -- Setting Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search, parameters

I want to take a form that has purchase options, and the user can filter an inventory to find what they are looking for, such as:

Color:
_Blue
_Green
_Red

Size:
_Large
_Medium
_Small

And have those options be check boxes, so they can see what is in stock.

My idea is to have a form that is submitted using an "update inventory" submit button (if anyone knows of a way to have it automatically updated rather than having a user click a button that would be amazing).

The form once submitted will perform a database search and return the objects that meet the parameters:

```
def find_items
    @products = Product.where(:color => params[:color], :size => params[:size])
    redirect_to '/products/search'
end
```

However, from my understanding if a checkbox is checked it will return 1. Is there a way to alter this behavior to maybe have it submit something like "blue" or "medium", and what if nothing is checked? / Multiple items are checked? Is this going to work?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you want to submit one value for color and one value for size. Use radio buttons, check boxes are for posting multiple values at once.

You try doing it like this:-

```
Blue <%=radio_button_tag 'color', 'blue' %>
Green <%=radio_button_tag 'color', 'green' %>
red <%=radio_button_tag 'color', 'red' %>
```

If none of the radio button is selected the empty value is posted to controller. So, you have to handle it accordingly.